# Deleting rows inside tableview while using sender.tag

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My `tableView` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks like so:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CheckoutAppointmentCell.reuseIdentifier) as! CheckoutAppointmentCell
    cell.appointment = appointments[indexPath.row]
    cell.checkoutButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.checkoutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkoutButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

And then I remove the appointment from the `tableView` and `dataSource` like so:

```
func checkoutButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    appointments.remove(at: sender.tag)
    print(sender.tag)
    //self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row:sender.tag, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    //self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

The first time I remove an appointment, it works fine. The `sender.tag` value is what it should be and the correct row is removed from the `tableView`.

After removing the first row, it seems to remove the incorrect row afterwards.

I have tried calling `reloadData()` after calling `deleteRows` but the animation no longer occurs. `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` seems to make no difference neither.

Comment: what you actually mean by this line-:After removing the first row, it seems to remove the incorrect row afterwards? Can you explain bit what it does afterwards?

Comment: So when I tap the `checkoutButton`, it calls `checkoutButtonTapped`.   The `sender.tag` is the correct value upon the first removal of a row.  E.g I tap the checkoutButton for row 2, the sender.tag is 2 thus removing row 2 from the table view.  After the first removal, the sender.tag is no longer the correct value E.g I might interact with row 3, but the `sender.tag` value will be row 4

Comment: Never use tags to represent index paths. As you see here, deleting, inserting, or moving rows in the table view leaves all remaining rows with the wrong index path tag.

Comment: @rmaddy What other method could I use to update my table view datasource correctly while making use of the table view delete row animation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using tags to track index paths is a common but very poor practice. It fails in any table view that allows rows to be deleted, inserted, or moved because remaining cells now have invalid tags unless the table view is fully reloaded using `reloadData`.

The better solution that doesn't require the use of `reloadData` to keep tags up-to-date, is to determine the `indexPath` of the cell's button based on the button's location.

```
func checkoutButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let hitPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableView)
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: hitPoint) {
        // use indexPath to get needed data
    }
}
```

Comment: `hitPoint` is of type is of type `CGPoint`.  From autocompletion I found `indexPathForRow(at point: )` . I'm guessing it's meant to be this?

Comment: Oops. That was a typo. Answer is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know it is good idea or not but it  also seems to work fine using `CallBack Closures`, as using tags are not good idea.

As some points suggested by @rmaddy I updated answer accordingly.

**CustomCell Class-:**

```
  import UIKit

class testingCell: UITableViewCell {

    var deleteCallBack : ((testingCell)->())?// CallBack function

    @IBOutlet weak var parentlabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func deleteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Call your closure 
        if let callBack = deleteCallBack{
            callBack(self)
        }
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

**Controller class-:**

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}// Default is 1 if not implemented

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    // return number of rows in section
    return data.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! testingCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]

    cell.deleteCallBack = { [weak self] tableCell in
        //Print indexPath for selected Cell
        print(self?.dataTableView.indexPath(for: tableCell) as Any )

        if let selectedIndex  = self?.dataTableView.indexPath(for: tableCell) {
            // Print selected row
            print(selectedIndex.row)
            // delete row from array
            self?.data.remove(at: selectedIndex.row)
            // Get index row to be deleted from table
            let indePath = NSIndexPath(item: selectedIndex.row, section: selectedIndex.section)
            // delete row from table
            self?.dataTableView.deleteRows(at: [indePath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        }

    }
    return cell
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    // Return cell height
    return 100
}
```

**It is indeed printing out correct index after deletion.**

Comment: 1. Do not force unwrap `deleteCallBack`. The app will crash if it isn't set. 2. You should pass the cell as an argument to the callback. 3. Do not call `reloadData` to remove one row.